# function not working R

Tags: r, function

I've never programmed before and am trying to learn. I'm following that "coursera" course that I've seen other people post about — a course offered by Johns Hopkins on R programming.

Anyway, this was supposed to be my first function. Yet, it doesn't work! But when I type out all the steps individually, it runs just fine... Can anyone tell me why?

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
    x<- list.files("/Users/mike******/Desktop/directory", full.names=TRUE)
    y<- lapply(x, read.csv)
    z<- do.call(rbind.data.frame, y[id])

    mean(z$pollutant, na.rm=TRUE)
}
pollutantmean(specdata,nitrate,1:10)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(z$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

####

x<- list.files("/Users/mike******/Desktop/specdata",full.names=TRUE)
y<- lapply(x,read.csv)
z<- do.call(rbind.data.frame,y[1:10])
mean(z$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0.7976266
```

Answer (score 2):

The step-by-step code is not the same as the function.  In the function you have this:

```
mean(z$pollutant, na.rm=TRUE)
```

In the step-by-step code, you have this:

```
mean(z$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Given the error message (and the column name), I suspect that `pollutant` is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

From ?"$"

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is
>   equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

NB "$ does not allow computed indices"

so your line

```
mean(z$pollutant, na.rm=TRUE)
```

needs to be

```
mean(z[[pollutant]], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Edited to add:
... and in the call `pollutant` needs to be a character variable, not a name i.e.

```
pollutantmean(specdata,"nitrate",1:10)
```

Further, your function does not use the argument `directory`. I guess you need to follow Rodrigo's advice on that point.

Answer (score -1):

This line

```
list.files("/Users/mike******/Desktop/directory", full.names=TRUE)
```

should be

```
list.files(paste("/Users/mike******/Desktop/",directory,sep=""), full.names=TRUE)
```

Beyond that, there seems to be a problem in your column nitrate too. Perhaps inside the function you should try

```
mean(z[,pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
```

and the function calling should be

```
pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate",1:10)
```

I hope that helps.